# trying to get a 'Search Bar and Display Controller' to repopulate a table view

Tags: ios, ios5

I am trying to get the 'Search Bar and Display Controller' functionality to work in an iOS app. I am able to NSLog in repsonse to a search query and hardcode in a new array but am unable to get the table view to repopulate. I have the following for in response to a user submit on the search button:

```
- (void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar{
  NSLog(@"You clicked the search bar");
  NSMutableArray *filteredResults=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

  Person *filteredPerson=[[Person alloc] init];
  filteredPerson.firstName=@"Josie - here i am";
  [filteredResults addObject:filteredPerson];
  _objects=filteredResults;
  self.tableView.dataSource = _objects;
  [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

Any ideas on making this repopulate would be appreciated.

thx

**edit #1**
It looks like this is populating the _objects NSMutableArray:

```
- (void)insertNewObject:(id)sender
{
    if (!_objects) {
        _objects = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }
    [_objects insertObject:[NSDate date] atIndex:0];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];
    [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
}
```

Should I just create a new _objects and use insertNewObject rather than the addObject code I have above? Would this bypass the need to deal with the dataSource property of the table view?

**edit 2**
per @ian

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
    }

    /*
    NSDate *object = [_objects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = [object description];
    */

    Person *rowPerson = [_objects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = [rowPerson firstName];

    return cell;
}
```

thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a UITableView that uses an NSMutableArray to  hold the data. Here's how it works: set the UISearchDisplayController's delegate to your TableView controller, and when the UITableViewDelegate methods are called (numberOfRows, numberOfSections, cellForRowAtIndexPath, etc) you can do the following to serve up the search data when appropriate:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    NSInteger numberOfRows = 0;

    if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView)
    {
        //This is your search table --- use the filteredListContent (this is the NSMutableArray)
        numberOfRows = [filteredListContent count];
    }
    else
    {
        //Serve up data for your regular UITableView here.
    }

    return numberOfRows;
}
```

You should take a look at the [UISearchDisplayDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UISearchDisplayDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) documentation. You can use these methods to update your filteredListContent array, as follows:

```
#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Content Filtering

- (void)filterContentForSearchText:(NSString*)searchText
{   
    //In this method, you'll want to update your filteredListContent array using the string of text that the user has typed in. For example, you could do something like this (it all depends on how you're storing and retrieving the data):

    NSPredicate *notePredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"text contains[cd] %@", searchText];
    self.filteredListContent = [[mainDataArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:notePredicate] mutableCopy];
    }


#pragma mark UISearchDisplayController Delegate Methods
- (BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller shouldReloadTableForSearchString:(NSString *)searchString
{
    [self filterContentForSearchText:searchString];

    // Return YES to cause the search result table view to be reloaded.
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: the filteredListContent and the NSMutableArray used for initial population are different, right?

Comment: For my app, the filteredListContent is an NSMutableArray, and my data source for the non-search UITableView is a Core Data repository. What do you mean by "initial population"?

Comment: so you basically have two separate UITableViews - the initial data which is your core data piece and then an NSMutableArray. What I really want is to figure out how to make the search results populate the same view which seems much simpler (or just get the returned results to populate a new table view)

Comment: A UISearchDisplayController has its own UITableView; that's how it works by default. Hence there are two tableviews in this code. http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UISearchDisplayController_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Answer (score 0):

The line `self.tableView.dataSource = _objects;` is setting your array as the datasource for the UITableView. I assume that you don't have an NSArray subclass that implements the `UITableViewDataSource` protocol?

Try removing that line, and letting your existing datasource handler deal with the change in data.

Comment: should have included that this is first time using UISearchBar so please be gentle

Comment: I added an edit above - does this make sense? Sorry, I know this is so basic.

Comment: Have you used a UITableView before, and populated data via the UITableViewDataSource protocol? (tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: etc)

Comment: yep - added the cellForRowAtIndexPath - first time doing any searchBar code and trying to separate out what is magic and what I need to put in. Not getting fully where _objects gets put into the table view and how to have that work in response to the seach button clicked code above

Comment: Did you try removing the line as I suggested? self.tableView.datasource = _objects;